# Overriding layoutAttributesForElements(in:) in a UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout subclass

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am looking to subclass UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout with the objective of overriding `layoutAttributesForElement(in:)` to get the initial layout attributes using `super.layoutAttributesForElement(in: rect)` and modifying the attributes if some of them are overlapping (some of my items will bleed into other sections, and if an item is overlapping with another item that I want it to move one of them down until they no longer overlap).

Are there any possible issues with this? One I’m suspecting is if layoutAttributesForItem(at:) is called then I could run into some issues since I can’t do what I’m trying to do by overriding this function.

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: @Vjy I've went ahead and overriden layoutAttributesForElements(in:) as I described and it works, but there's some bugs that I've yet to work out related to drag and drop because I haven't worked on the project in a few weeks.

Comment: @HunterMeyer how did you do this without getting a crash?

Comment: I was able to subclass the UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout to use it for decorationView attributes. @RichardWitherspoon You can initialise your own class in the createLayout() function. However there are some bugs where decorationViews flicker and reuse issues that I am struggling with.